# python 3.3.2 function definition multi parameter syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

i have a code something like this:

```
a=1.
b=2.

c=(a,b)

def test((a,b),c):
    return a+b+c

test(c,5)
```

However, it says that there is a syntax error in second paranthesis of: def test((a,b),c)

Any suggestions? (btw this works fine for 2.6.1, i have 3.3.2, i could not find any syntax change regarding this)

Answer (score 4):

That feature -- tuple parameter unpacking -- was removed from Python 3: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

You should rewrite your code:

```
def test(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

test(c[0], c[1], 5)
```

or

```
def test(a, b):
    return a[0] + a[1] + b

test(c, 5)
```

Comment: the link that you gave was very helpful, thx.

Answer (score 1):

From [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax):

> Tuple parameter unpacking removed. You can no longer write `def foo(a,
>   (b, c)): ....` Use `def foo(a, b_c): b, c = b_c` instead.

Related PEP: [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113)